# Greasemonkey fails to load simple script

Tags: firefox, windows-7, greasemonkey

I've been using Greasemonkey successfully at work for a week or so with no problems (on a MacOS) - I have *Smultron* configured as my default editor, and can simply save changes to a script, reload the page and observe the changes.  All is well.

However, on my Windows 7 machine at home (FF 16 & Greasemonkey 1.4), I am utterly failing at getting a simple alert("Hello World") script to run.  I've uninstalled both GM & FF already, and rolled back to FF 14 (the version I'm running at work) to no avail.

config.xml:

```
<UserScriptConfig>
 <Script basedir="test" checkRemoteUpdates="1" dependhash="." description="a test
of the test" enabled="true" filename="test.user.js" installTime="." modified="." 
name="test" namespace="." runAt="document-end" updateAvailable="" uuid="." version="1" 
installurl="." updateurl=".">
 <Grant>none</Grant>
 <Include>*</Include>
 </Script>
</UserScriptConfig>
```

test.user.js:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @namespace   www.test.com
// @description a test of the test
// @include     *
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

alert("fafdadfadfdaf");
```

The script is located in the proper base directory (test/...).  This morning, after turning the computer on, I attempted to run a similar test script and it suddenly worked, however, when I modified it and saved it (ie changed the alert text), Greasemonkey continued to run the old version of the script.  I even deleted both the `config.xml` and the offending script, and upon page reloads the script continued to fire along merrily.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** In this case it appears to be Firefox profile corruption.  Had the OP create a new profile using [Firefox's *Profile Manager*](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles), and he reports that that cleared up the problem.  See the comments below.

---

It sounds like either you are not editing the correct file, or the editor is not saving the changes to the correct location.

1. Determine your actual profile folder by following the directions at ["How do I find my profile?"](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile).
   The active copies of Greasemonkey scripts will be in the `gm_scripts` subfolder, in this profile folder.
2. See where Greasemonkey says your script is:

   1. Left-click on the Greasemonkey menu arrow:
      [image: Greasemonkey menu arrow]
   2. Right-click on the Greasemonkey script you wish to edit:
      [image: rt-click targ]
   3. If your editor is configured correctly, it will open to the live version of the file.
3. Make sure the editor saves the changed file to the same location (some windows editors don't always).
4. Don't edit `config.xml`.  This is almost never necessary and changes are often overwritten anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Unfortunately, the files are being saved in the correct profile directory (...\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\blahblah\gm_scripts.  Just to be sure, I've clicked the monkey menu you screenshotted above, selected "New User Script..." and created the same simple alert("Hello World"); script - still it does nothing.

Comment: In the GreaseMonkey dropdown menu, the script does show as active:  "[x] test", but it simply does not run.  Tampermonkey in Chrome works fine on my system, but I definitely prefer working with Firefox and its beloved offspring, Firebug.

Comment: What does the FF Error console (Ctrl-Shift-J) show?  Use Firefox's *Profile Manager* to create, and run, a new profile.  Install *only* GM in that profile and retest.

Comment: Error Console shows absolutely nothing related to GreaseMonkey (errors and warnings with .css etc. on whatever site I'm visiting only).  Is there any reason to do the "Create New Profile" thing when I've done completely fresh installs of Firefox (currently the lastest version?)  Upon trying the GM_css injection, GM_log, etc. there is no response / activity.

Comment: Yes.  "Fresh installs" often do not replace the profile and from your reports, profile corruption is a strong possibility. And, what happened to the simple `alert()` script? Did that work before you moved on to "GM_css injection, GM_log, etc."?

Comment: The "fresh install" was not so fresh after all - as you said, it must've been a corrupted profile that was causing the mayhem.  I created a new profile, ran a test script an voila! everything is working as expected.  Attempting to do *anything* within the corrupt profile--from the simple alert("Hello") to any of the GM API (GM_log, etc) produced no response, and no discernible errors in the console, just in case this helps others troubleshoot.  Thanks again for the help - now I am enveloped in the zen of Greasemonkey once again.